# OnFling and ImageView not working correctly

Tags: android, imageview, gesture, gesturedetector, onfling

So I'm trying to get the imageview component of my page to change on swipe. I'm not even able to pick up the swipe gesture and forward it onto the Gesture Detector.

In the OnFling method, I'm not able to get to those log statements. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
public class Detail extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ImageView wallpaper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
            wallpaper = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.wallpaper);
    wallpaper.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

            wallpaper.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("getting", "here");
                            //return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
                    }
            });
}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            Log.d("MOTION", "STARTED");
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                Log.d("Moving", "Right");
                return true;

            }  
            else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                Log.d("Moving", "Left");
                return true;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice example
http://www.androidsnippets.com/gesturedetector-and-gesturedetectorongesturelistener

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I have a class called GenesMotionDetector.java. Here's the code for it:

```
package gene.com.motioneventssample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

//This works
public class GenesMotionDetector extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetector gestureScanner;
    LinearLayout mView1;
    TextView mView2;
    ImageView mView3;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nothing);
        gestureScanner= new GestureDetector(getBaseContext(),this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        System.out.println("Inside onTouchEvent() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onDown() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        System.out.println("Inside onFling() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onLongPress() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        System.out.println("Inside onScroll() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onShowPress() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Inside onSingleTapUp() of GenesMotionDetector.java");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The corresponding XML layout file for that class is nothing.xml. Here's the code for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:background="#17528c"
        android:text="testing"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:background="#f8af20"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set

```
mDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);
```

Longpress is enabled (true) by default and what that does is listen for the longpress event only and discards scrolling, flinging and other complicated events.

Just put that code in after you setup your gesture detector object:

```
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, this);
mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
mDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(false);
```

Peace